# Exception while connecting Couchbase server using .net connectors

Tags: .net, database, c#-4.0, couchbase, nosql

I am getting exception while connecting `couchbase cluster` (server) using `.Net SDK`, using latest `.net connectors for Couchbase server`. Attaching C# code and App.config.

**Exception:**

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in
>   System.Configuration.dll Additional information: Unrecognized
>   attribute 'OperationLifeSpan'. Note that attribute names are
>   case-sensitive."

Please help me if I am missing something here,

**C# Code:**

```
public static void CreateOrder()
{
    using (var cluster = new Cluster("couchbaseClients/couchbase"))
    {
        IBucket bucket = null;

        try
        {
            bucket = cluster.OpenBucket();

            var order = new Document<Order>()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Content = new Order()
                {
                    Name="Tiffin",
                    Location="WITP",
                    Quantity=2
                }
            };

            var result = bucket.Insert(order);

            if (result.Success)
                Console.WriteLine("Order Created '{0}'", order.Id);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (bucket != null)
                cluster.CloseBucket(bucket);
        }
    }
}
```

**Config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="couchbaseClients">
      <section name="couchbase"
               type="Couchbase.Configuration.Client.Providers.CouchbaseClientSection, Couchbase.NetClient"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <couchbaseClients>
    <couchbase useSsl="false" operationLifeSpan="1000">
      <servers>
        <add uri="http://192.168.56.101:8091/pools"></add>
        <add uri="http://192.168.56.102:8091/pools"></add>
        <add uri="http://192.168.56.103:8091/pools"></add>
        <add uri="http://192.168.56.104:8091/pools"></add>
      </servers>
      <buckets>
        <add name="default" useSsl="false" password="" operationLifespan="2000">
          <connectionPool name="custom" maxSize="10" minSize="5" sendTimeout="12000"></connectionPool>
        </add>
      </buckets>
    </couchbase>
  </couchbaseClients>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have upprecase S instead of lowercase s in operationLifespan.

try

```
    <couchbase useSsl="false" operationLifespan="1000">
```

instead of

```
    <couchbase useSsl="false" operationLifeSpan="1000">
```